# How can I use FOSUSER bundle having one table and multiple CRUDs in different bundles?

Tags: symfony, orm, entity, fosuserbundle

I have used FOSUSER bundle and created separate USERBundle  where I have overwritten FOSUSER Bundle for registration and login. Now I have one more bundle named "AdminBundle" where I need to use FOSUSER Entity,but without creating new table.

How can I achieve this. Is this possible or not?

After some research, I have created one controller and in that action I am using User Entity which is extending FOSUSER Bundle entity, but now I am getting another error. below are my code from controller

createForm(new UserFormType(), $user, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_create'),
            'method' => 'POST'
        ));

```
    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Feature entity.
 *
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $user = new User();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($user);

    return $this->render('EparAdminBundle:User:new.html.twig', array(
        'feature' => $user,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

?>
 And the error I am getting is "ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType::__construct(),"

Apart from controller I have created UserFormType but not able to understand how to get FOSBUNDLE form fields

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by `"I need to use FOSUSER Entity"`? You can use any entity from any bundle within your project!! Could you please explain little more about your use case.

Comment: Yes you should re-use the same User entity that you should keep in a dedicated UserBundle. Then create as much UserFormType as you want in your other bundles.

Comment: I have created one controller and using User entity and then created UserFormType but it throws exception "ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "UserFormType" from namespace"

Comment: Now, I am able to resolve the namespace issue but i am getting below error  private function createCreateForm(User $user)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserFormType(), $user, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_create'),
            'method' => 'POST'
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }   "ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType::__construct()" please can you help me out